# Conditional rendering inputs overlap text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to make a form where, depending on a switch button, renders one or two different inputs.
My code looks like this:

```
const Test = () => {

const [switchButton, setSwitch] = React.useState(true)

const handleSwitch = () => {setstate(!switchButton)}

return <>
  <Switch checked={switchButton} onClick={() => handleSwitch} />
  {!switchButton ? 
    <>
       <label htmlFor="input_1">Input 1</label>
       <input id="input_1"/>
    </>
     :
    <>
       <label htmlFor="input_2">Input 2</label>
       <input id="input_2" />
       <label htmlFor="input_3">Input 3</label>
       <input id="input_3" />
    </>
  }
</>
}

export default Test;
```

My issue happens when I enter characters into one input and then switch them: The same characters are shown on my new rendered input. [Example here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byzvq.gif)

Why does this happen? I'm really lost

Comment: Where is variable `switch` defined?  State is `switchButton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use keys for the elements, so it will not be recognized as the same element as react tries to map elements on each rerender if they were already rendered before.
so react sees: 1 input and than 2 inputs and thinks the first input is the same as before.

```
const Test = () => {
  const [switchButton, setSwitch] = React.useState(true)
  const handleSwitch = () => setSwitch((switch) => !switch)

  return (
    <>
      <Switch checked={switch} onClick={handleSwitch} />
      {!switchButton ? (
        <React.Fragment key="key1">
          <label htmlFor="input_1">Input 1</label>
          <input id="input_1"/>
        </>
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment key="key2">
          <label htmlFor="input_2">Input 2</label>
          <input id="input_2" />
          <label htmlFor="input_3">Input 3</label>
          <input id="input_3" />
        </>
      )}
   </>
)}

export default Test;
```

but anyway it would be better to use a controlled input. something like this:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(true)

<input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why it works like that?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys